# 404 no such file or directory, php netbeans project

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, hierarchy

Ive got a Netbeans php project that looks like this:

```
PhpProject/ 
          projets/
                 uploadImage/ **resize.php** the file I run
                            assets/...
                            inc/ **empty.png** file I asked in a <img> html tag in the php file.
```

Problem is : I get a 404 on every file call inside hierarchy, whatever folder.

I tried to put the empty.png in the same folder as resize.php, this worked well.

I am on linux Kali, Ive looked for permissions in the project, this seems to be in read only mode.
Hierarchy was created on Netbeans.

Ive just noted that this line in resize.php works. So it can find and access a file in the folder. `<link rel='stylesheet' href="inc/styleSheet.css">`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it seems that I needed to use the index.php as a starting page, from this file I can access the whole hierarchy.
Dont really understand why but its fixed.